# Disconnecting from SSH session whilst continuing to run process, then rejoining it

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

I log on to an ssh session via

```
ssh user@name.of.session
```

I then run a code via `./main`

From here, I'd like to disconnect completely from the ssh session and switch off my PC. I'd like for the process to keep running whilst I'm gone. What do I type into the command line to do this?

Secondly, once I reconnect to the SSH session, how do I stop the process running when I want?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is you learn how to use the `screen` command, that will do exactly what you want. There are some commands and shortcuts. And some youtube videos that show it being used.

If I wanted to SSH to a server and run wget on it to download a file onto it, then i'd do it having run screen. Otherwise as you suggest, disconnecting ssh would terminate whatever process eg wget, which is ridiculous.

You can ssh back in and do `screen -ls`  and see the processes and the screen -r command can be used to reattach to the screen you want.. and there's shortcuts like ctrl-d and ctrl-a

if I get some more time then I might try it later and refresh myself and be more specific re the commands. But what i've said gives more than enough info.

The screen command can also be used to split the window horizontally and vertically but i'm not talking about or referring to that usage.